# Put md-switch in the middle of the cards (AngularJS material design ,Css)

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-material

I want to create the same design like chrome settings page 
https://www.pcworld.com/article/3162716/software/how-to-switch-to-chromes-material-design-settings-page-for-an-easier-experience.html

I do not manage to put the `md-switch` at the right and in static position like chrome settings

I do manage to put the `md-switch` in right to the title but I need it always in the middle of the card stick to right.

Image of my result: (current design)

[image: Image of my result]

```
<md-card md-theme="{{ showDarkTheme ? 'dark-purple' : 'default' }}" md-theme-watch>
    <div class="option-item">
        <div class="option-item-header">
            <div class="option-item-header-title">
                title
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="option-body">
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="option-switch">
        <md-switch ng-model="vm.model" aria-label="active" ng-change="function()">      
        </md-switch>
    </div>
</md-card>
```

Comment: In the *middle* like in centered (horizontal) or like in vertical middle? (Also, in one place you talk about `ms-switch` and then about `md-switch`... Is it a typo?)

Comment: yes typo., fixed 
I want it in the middle like chrome setting (float to right and middle of div

Comment: In Chrome settings `md-switches` aren't in the middle of a group, but on the top-right corner... See: https://imgur.com/WqxomFY

Comment: Are you using Angular flexbox layout?